# Error: Call to a member function getTitleName() on a non-object

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I created the forms, I have the following error:

```
Call to a member function getTitleName() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\public_html\apps\frontend\modules\planbook\templates\_form.php on line 25
```

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo  url_for((!isset($planbook) ? '@planbook_create' : '@planbook_update').(isset($planbook) ? '?id='.$planbook->getId() : '')) ?>">
  <table>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          &nbsp;<a href="<?php echo url_for('planbook/index') ?>">Back to list</a>
          <?php if (!$form->getObject()->isNew()): ?><?php endif; ?>

          <input type="hidden" id="planbook_id" name="planbook[id]"  value="<?php echo isset($planbook) ?  $planbook->getId() : ' '?>" />
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <th>
        <lable for="planbook_titlename"> Title</label>
      </th>
      <td>
        <?php if(isset($editFormFields) && isset($editFormFields['titlename'])) :?>
          <input type="text" id="planbook_titlename" name="planbook[titlename]" value="<?php echo isset($planbook) ?  $planbook->getTitleName() : ''?>">
        <?php else: ?>
          <?php echo $planbook->getTitleName() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <label for="planbook_place">Place</label>
        </th>
        <td>
          <?php if(isset($editFormFields) && isset($editFormFields['place'])) :?>
            <input type="text" id="planbook_place" name="planbook[place]" value="<?php echo isset($planbook) ? $planbook->getPlace() : ''?>">
          <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $planbook->getPlace() ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try is_object($planbook)

Doctrine will usually return something, so is_null or isset may not be the best idea

Comment: Hi ,still have same problem.any idea.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your error, I guess you need to put this line before your form:

```
$planbook = $form->getObject();
```

And then replace all your `isset($planbook)` with `! $planbook->isNew()`.

---

**BUT** I think you're taking the wrong way of creating a form.

For example, this :

```
<?php if(isset($editFormFields) && isset($editFormFields['titlename'])) :?>
  <input type="text" id="planbook_titlename" name="planbook[titlename]" value="<?php echo isset($planbook) ?  $planbook->getTitleName() : ''?>">
<?php else: ?>
  <?php echo $planbook->getTitleName() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You don't need to do thing manually, like :

- display the input,
- generate the id and name,
- determine if you have to set the value if the object exists
- etc ..

Every thing is done with the form:

```
<?php echo $editFormFields['titlename']->renderRow() ?>
```

Please, [read the full doc related to the form](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms). And also, don't forget to give us all the code for your error. Here, you give us only a partial template.

- What about the actions?
- What about the form class (from where the `$form` comes) ?
- What about the main template (since you give us a partial, and the template that include this partial) ?

Comment: Hi,thanks lot solved that problem.but i submited the form. 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ned`.`planbook`, CONSTRAINT `planbook_personal_id_personal_id` FOREIGN KEY (`personal_id`) REFERENCES `personal` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE).this error was comming

Comment: This is an other error, we don't know all your project, your model, etc .. So if you want some help, please try to find the solution **FIRST** and then, if you don't find, give us all informations so we can help you. But **please**, don't just say "your solution works but I got a new error without trying to correct it". We are not psychic !